# Sliding doors CSS, button tags and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a project to upgrade a system to use the button tag rather than regular submit buttons. For the formatting of the buttons, I have the following CSS classes:

```
    button::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: none;  /* overrides extra padding in Firefox */
    }

    button {
      background: transparent url('images/greenrightbutton.png') no-repeat scroll top right;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: block;
      font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
      height: 25px;
      padding-right: 8px; /* sliding doors padding */
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 0px;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    #loginbox button {
      float: right;
    }
    button span {
      background: transparent url('images/greenleftbutton.png') no-repeat top left;
      display: block;
      line-height: 18px;
      padding: 4px 5px 5px 12px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 0px;
    }
```

They work absolutely perfectly in every browser except IE8.

In IE8, the buttons work in most places, but then I find a page where the two background images don't quite line up and no amount of tweaking padding, line spacing etc fixes it.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Demo page: http://test6.placement.co.uk/demo/test.asp

---Update---

After some fairly extensive testing and trying things, I've now got a pretty fair idea of what's causing the problem in page 1, but no idea how to fix it, while another page with the same issue has a completely different cause (which I haven't found) but where I HAVE stumbled on a fix...

The problem on the first page appears to relate to a ul entered further up the page. Take that out and everything behaves - unfortunately, that's not an option as the ul is part of user-entered content, so I'm scratching my head about that. Particularly given...

Page 2 has no uls to cause an issue, but randomly sticking two break tags in just before my button code resolves the problem.

Naturally, THAT fix doesn't work on page 1.

I'm just about ready to give in and find some alternative way of rendering these buttons, because whatever the actual problem is, it's clearly so deep in either my CSS or my basic HTML that I'm probably never going to find it.

Comment: can you link to a live version of the code to look at?

Comment: Unfortunately, most of this is being done on a private dev server, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: And, apparently, something I've taken out to make the test page is causing it because the test page seems to be behaving. Agh.

Comment: I can see that the text within the button moves slightly in IE 8, have you tried adding a CSS reset it should keep things more consistent across browsers. Alternatively you may be able to use an IE8 hack to change the padding on the span to even it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I'll give them both a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference between IE8 and other browser. Could you pleas mention bit more clear what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah - the demo page is actually working properly, frustratingly. The issue I'm seeing on my dev server is that the right hand edge of the image is jumping up by a couple of pixels (or the left hand side is dropping down by a couple of pixels) leading to a noticeable glitch in the button's border.

Comment: Try writing separate style sheet for IE8 and call that style sheet in main page. Give the same class name in IE8 style sheet with the proper styles to align the image.